# I have created a point cut for base package execution( * com.blk.example.*.*.*)" but @advice method is not calling at all..?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

AOP `@Around` is not calling at all for base package point cut. Below is the code I am using. It should show me start time, end time, time taken but "AOP method" is not firing at all for any controller, service method within the base package.

```java
@Aspect
@Configuration
public  class LoggerAOP {
    private static final Logger logger = oggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerAOP.class);

    @Around("execution(* com.example.platform.test.*.*.*(..))")
    public void customAOPMetrics(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        MDC.put("CorelationalId", UUID.randomUUID());
        MDC.put("eventId", UUID.randomUUID());

        logger.info(pjp.getSignature().getName() + " called with ");
        logger.info(Arrays.toString(pjp.getArgs()));

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Start time: " + startTime);

        try {
            pjp.proceed();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error occured: " + ex.getStackTrace());
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("End Time :" + endTime);
        long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
        MDC.clear();
        logger.info("Time taken: " + timeTaken);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many possible reasons aspects not kicking in. So before I answer, a few questions: Have you verified that Spring AOP works at all in your project, e.g. with a different pointcut? Have you made sure your aspect is a `@Component` and being picked up by component scan? Are the target classes also Spring components?

Comment: @kriegaex yes when i gave complete pkg for service ,its kicking.

Answer (score 0):

> @kriegaex: Yes, when I gave complete pkg for service, it's kicking

Then the explanation is simple: Your pointcut does not capture the classes and methods you expect it to:

```
execution(* com.example.platform.test.*.*.*(..))
```

This would e.g. capture

```
com.example.platform.test.foo.ClassA.methodX(..)
com.example.platform.test.bar.ClassB.methodY(..)
```

But not

```
com.example.platform.test.ClassA.methodX(..)
com.example.platform.test.foo.bar.ClassA.methodX(..)
```

This is because you gave an exact number of subpackages (1) + class name + method name with `.*.*.*`. You are more flexible like this:

```
execution(* com.example.platform.test..*(..))
```

It will capture all of the above because `..` says: No matter how many packages and class names in between, capture all methods in `com.example.platform.test` and all sub-packages.